# booked on showing, not touching. Is he a flasher?

Tags: meaning-in-context

First, a little bit of the context: In episode 5 of "Fresh Off the Boat", an american sitcom series, a repeat sexual harassment ex-offender gives a talk about sexual harassment and he says, "thanks to a complicated plea deal, is now working for the good guys. That's right. They hannibal lectered me. Don't be alarmed. **I booked on showing, not touching.** ".

I guess the meaning of the last bold sentence is like "I was booked by the police on the subject of exhibitionism, instead of molestation". Is my guess close enough?

Comment: You are correct.

Answer (score -1):

In the TV show Fresh Off the Boat" the family lives in [Orlando Florida](https://freshofftheboat.fandom.com/wiki/808_Meadowridge_Lane)

[Florida's definition of this crime is](https://www.husseinandwebber.com/crimes/public-order-obstruction/exposure-of-sexual-organs/):

> “It is unlawful to expose or exhibit one’s sexual organs in public or
> on the private premises of another, or so near thereto as to be seen
> from such private premises, in a vulgar or indecent manner, or to be
> naked in public except in any place provided or set apart for that
> purpose.”

The definition of [exhibitionism](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/exhibitionism) is

> : a perversion in which sexual gratification is obtained from the indecent exposure of one's genitals (as to a stranger)

So yes the meaning would be the same.